# How to send Auth token in every request react native (Functional components & React hooks) using actions and reducers?

Tags: react-native, redux, functional-programming, react-hooks

Using AsyncStorage in react native how to achieve this?

I am new to React native I have all the APIs integrated without authorization

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-sensitive-info` for storing your auth token securely:

```
SInfo.setItem('token', 'value');
```

then you can read like this:

```
SInfo.getItem('token');
```

for adding auth token to every request:

- if you are using `axios`: create an axios instance and config the authorization header
- if you are using `fetch` function: define a function for requesting to the server, config the authorization header in this function and send all of your requests with this function

hope to solve your problem...